# Recovering an ECPublicKey from Java to JavaCard

Tags: java, cryptography, javacard, apdu, elliptic-curve

This question is related to the one I asked yesterday : [Recovering an ECPublicKey from JavaCard to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733932/recovering-an-ecpublickey-from-javacard-to-java)

I have the same problem but in the opposite way :
After sending the public key from my card to my computer (the point is represented as an octet string in uncompressed form as per ANSI X9.62) I can recover the corresponding key.

But I can't recover it on my card if I send it from my computer, I get a `CryptoException` (`ILLEGAL_VALUE`) which means that the form isn't correct or the point doesn't match with the curve parameter.

I verified, my parameters are well defined and I send the point in the right form...

To debug it, I try to send the public key from my card to my computer, and resend it to my card to try to recover it (so I'm sure that parameters are fine). Whatever, I still get the same error...

To illustrate my problem, I post the corresponding code:

On the card side - *to send the public key* :

```
pubKey = (ECPublicKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(
            KeyBuilder.TYPE_EC_FP_PUBLIC, (short) 0x0100, false);
pubKey.setFieldFP(p, (short) 0x0001, (short) 0x0020);
pubKey.setA(a, (short) 0x0001, (short) 0x0020);
pubKey.setB(b, (short) 0x0000, (short) 0x0020);
pubKey.setR(r, (short) 0x0001, (short) 0x0020);
pubKey.setG(g, (short) 0x0000, (short) g.length);

privKey = (ECPrivateKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(
        KeyBuilder.TYPE_EC_FP_PRIVATE, (short) 0x0100, false);

KeyPair keypair = new KeyPair(pubKey, privKey);
    keypair.genKeyPair();

short len = pubKey.getW(apduBuffer, (short) 0x0000);
setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0x0000, len);
```

The response sent is:

```
APDU <<<: 04C2B28FBE96C5EAC1E81750E9B288B0BD8357D3AED4EA39413197D734B145EBC92F3FD7489B9A7EF4C8A956427668851F0BB3A55D5C7B9033A533F21463E1A2139000
```

So the first coordinate is `x = C2B28FBE96C5EAC1E81750E9B288B0BD8357D3AED4EA39413197D734B145EBC9` and the second one, `y = 2F3FD7489B9A7EF4C8A956427668851F0BB3A55D5C7B9033A533F21463E1A213`

On the computer side - *to recover the key and resend it*:

```
byte[] x = new byte[32];
byte[] y = new byte[32];
System.arraycopy(W, 1, x, 0, x.length);
System.arraycopy(W, 1 + x.length, y, 0, y.length);

ECPublicKeySpec pub = new ECPublicKeySpec(new ECPoint(new BigInteger(1,x), new BigInteger(1,y)), ecParamSpec);

ECPublicKey ecPubKey = (ECPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(pub);

byte[] k_x = ecPubKey.getEncoded();

byte[] tmp = new byte[70];
tmp[0] = (byte) 0x80;
tmp[1] = (byte) 0x20;
tmp[2] = (byte) 0x00;
tmp[3] = (byte) 0x00;
tmp[4] = (byte) (65);
System.arraycopy(k_x, k_x.length - 65, tmp, 5,65);

sendApdu(cardChan, tmp);
```

The APDU sent is:

```
APDU >>>: 802000004104C2B28FBE96C5EAC1E81750E9B288B0BD8357D3AED4EA39413197D734B145EBC92F3FD7489B9A7EF4C8A956427668851F0BB3A55D5C7B9033A533F21463E1A213
```

So we can easily see that the data which is sent is **exactly** the same that the one received before.

And, finally, on the card side, I have the following code to recover the key:

```
pubKey.setW(apduBuffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA,
            ISO7816.OFFSET_LC);

len = pubKey.getW(apduBuffer, (short) 0x0000);
setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0x0000, len);
```

But I get `APDU >>>: 0401`

Which means `CryptoException.ILLEGAL_VALUE` that is raised at the instruction

```
pubKey.setW(apduBuffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA,
                ISO7816.OFFSET_LC);
```

How can it raises an Exception knowing that I send the same thing that I get by `pubKey.getW()`?

Comment: May I ask "what does that `04` means in the starting of response"?

Comment: In the reponses which corresponds to the public key from the card :
`APDU <<<: 04C2B28FBE96C5EAC1E81750E9B288B0BD8357D3AED4EA39413197D734B145EBC92F3FD7489B9A7EF4C8A956427668851F0BB3A55D5C7B9033A533F21463E1A2139000`
the `04` means that the point isn't compressed, and then you have the 2 coordinates of the point, you can check the linked post I mention at the beginning.
Concerning `APDU >>>: 0401` it is a home made Exception (04 for `CryptoException` and 01 for `ILLEGAL_VALUE`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely:

```
pubKey.setW(apduBuffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, ISO7816.OFFSET_LC);
```

First of all, you should not use `ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA` and `ISO7816.OFFSET_LC` directly. Use `APDU.getOffsetCData` for the location of the command data and use `APDU.setIncomingAndReceive` to get the Nc value (Lc is the *encoding of the Nc value*).

Currently your code is failing as you use `ISO7816.OFFSET_LC` instead of the output of `setIncomingAndReceive`. `ISO7816.OFFSET_LC` is a constant set to the value 4. Your public point is bigger than that.

Comment: That's a new record for an accept to happen to one of my answers. Shame that there are no badges for that :)

Comment: Well I am definitly blind now, and in fact it requiers more than 4 bytes :) ty

Comment: What does the first comment mean? I guess the answer accepted immediatelly after posting. Am I right? :)

Comment: @Abraham Yeah, in a few minutes after.