# Constructing an ECPublic Key in Java from Java Card

Tags: java, cryptography, smartcard, javacard, elliptic-curve

This question relates to this one here: [Recovering an ECPublicKey from JavaCard to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733932/recovering-an-ecpublickey-from-javacard-to-java)

However in the answer it isn't explained how to extract x and y - how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'w' value is made up of the x and y values.

The first byte should be either 04, 02 or 03 - which indicates if it is uncompressed or compressed. The last two bytes are status bytes, e.g. 90 00.

The remaining bytes are the x, then y value, which are both the same length

Comment: I miss the grouping information: x and y are supposed to have the same length.

Comment: Yes they are - let me edit my answer to include that